# How to format BigDecimal with 2 fractions?

Tags: java, currency, bigdecimal

I'd like to format and display `BigDecimal` numbers with always to fractions. No other separators should ever be displayed. How could I achieve it? The following does not work.

```
NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMANY);
formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
formatter.setMinimumIntegerDigits(2);
Sysout(formatter.format(new BigDecimal(100))); //would expect "100,00", but printout is "100"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `setMinimumFractionDigits` will set the minimum number of digits in the fraction portion of the number.

```
NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMANY);
formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
formatter.setMinimumIntegerDigits(2);
formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
System.out.println((formatter.format(new BigDecimal(100)))); // prints "100,00"
```

Comment: You have `setMaximumFractionDigits` twice. The OP already had it.

Comment: You're right, thanks. I thought it was `setMaximumIntegerDigits`. Will update it.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a custom format of

```
0.00
```

Like so:

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.00", DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY));
```

This will force any incoming number for have to decimals.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this.

```
 aBigDecimal.SetScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BigDecimal d=new BigDecimal("100");
d=d.setScale(2, RoundingMode.CEILING);
System.out.println(d);
```